# Xcode 7 warning loadNibNamed:owner is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nib

Firstly this issue is for Xcode project written in Objective-C for Mac OSX Application.

I am getting the warning "loadNibNamed:owner is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.8" for the following line:

`[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"StartMyDialog" owner:self];`

However it still seems to work fine for now. After some Googling I found the following solution:

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StartMyDialog" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];`

This removes the warning, but when I run my project the nib view does not appear, even though the aforementioned line returns TRUE which indicates that the nib file has successfully loaded. Is there something else I need to do to make it appear? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From NSBundle documentation:

> **Discussion**
>
> Unlike legacy methods, the objects adhere to the standard cocoa memory management rules; it is necessary to keep a strong reference to them by using IBOutlets or holding a reference to the array to prevent the nib contents from being deallocated.
>
> Outlets to top-level objects should be strong references to demonstrate ownership and prevent deallocation.

So you need to make your top-level objects strong like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
```